# Hide Only the First Row from the Dataset (but still will be used and acessed in Database) So Only Hide Donot remove

Tags: vb.net, dataset

Hi I have a Data set called DSrules which fetches Few records from a Table. Now i need to Hide only the First Row of this Data set Fully.

```
Public Property DSRules() As DataSet
```

This is my Dataset Now how do i hide only the first row from this Dataset in Vb.net I am new to Vb.net Please help.

Comment: What means _hide_? There is no hide feature. You dont want to see this row but you haven't mentioned where you display it. Apart from that, why you can't modify the select that fills the DataTable so that the first row is not part of the result-set?

Comment: there is an DataGrid in my screen named dgrules in this grid these records from the dataset is displayed, but now i need to hide the first row of this Grid.

Comment: I had an idea of removing the first row from the dataset and again calling the Value of the row in the Method where the SP is called. So that i get back its values as it is. But this could actually causes more problem to my existing code. So just want to hide it in my Datagrid and not in the Code. 
Please help

Comment: i mean not remove only hide.

Comment: Create another datatable which  contains rows without first one. `Dim datatable = DSRules.Tables("myTable").AsEnumerable().Skip(1).CopyToDatatable();`

Comment: But the Table from which the records are fetched are being called and fetched through the stored procedure and not table. hence Tables("myTable") would not display the records.

Comment: Could you please remove my question ban

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer since i was not able to hide the row in the dataset, i went and removed the row and added it in another dataset and imported it to the existing for rest of the function. Thank you all for your help.